# Gitlab runner does not seem to load docker image

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

For a old codebase, we're trying to go from just uploading changes through FTP to using Gitlab CI/CD. However, none of us have extensive Gitlab experience, and I've been trying to set the deployment up by following this guide:

https://savjee.be/2019/04/gitlab-ci-deploy-to-ftp-with-lftp/

I'm running a gitlab-runner on my own mac right now, however, it seems like the docker image in my yml file is not loaded correctly. When using the yml from the article:

```
image: ubuntu:18.04

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y lftp

build:
  script:
    # Sync to FTP
    - lftp -e "open ftp.mywebhost.com; user $FTP_USERNAME $FTP_PASSWORD; mirror -X .* -X .*/ --reverse --verbose --delete local-folder/ destination-folder/; bye"
```

It tells me `apt-get: command not found`. I've tried with apk-get as well, but no differences. I've tried to find a different docker image that has lftp installed ahead of time, but then I just get a `lftp: command not found`:

```
image: minidocks/lftp:4

before_script:
  # - apt-get update -qy
  #- apt-get install -y lftp

build:
  script:
    - lftp -e "open ftp.mywebhost.com; user $FTP_USERNAME $FTP_PASSWORD; mirror -X .* -X .*/ --reverse --verbose --delete local-folder/ destination-folder/; bye"
    - echo 'test this'
```

If I comment out the lftp/apt-get bits, I do get to the echo command, however (and it does work).

I can't seem to find any reason for this when searching online. Apologies if this is a duplicate question or I've just been looking in the wrong places.

Comment: Which executor did you choose when you installed the runner on your machine ?

Comment: I think I picked the shell executor. I was under the impression I had to pick that one since I was running it from my command line, but I'm assuming from the question that's not how it works?

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/#compatibility-chart => shell executor does not handle the `image` tag. The executor type you actually want is docker.

Comment: Thanks for the help, time to go use that executor then.

Comment: @Zeitounator that was indeed the problem. If you could post a reply so I can mark it as answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question, it seems you are executing your tasks on a gitlab-runner using the shell executor.

The shell executor does not handle the `image` keyword as exposed in [the runner compatibility matrix](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/#compatibility-chart).

Moreover, since you want to deploy on docker containers, you need the [docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) anyway.